# How to write a query to find tables which have similar columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am looking to write a query to find out tables which have similar columns.
The reason is because in our test environment, no one has cleaned anything for ages and it would help us sort it out and bring the tables out which have similar columns.

Currently, there are 200 tables in the database and it is hard to find out which contains similar information as some of the tables names would be different but the fields would be same.

eg.

Table A would look like:

*ID  Name Description*

Table B would look like:

*ID Name*

And Table B may or may not contain the same data.

My Idea is to get the result in this format.

[image: Result]

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What is the measure of similarity?  Percent columns with the same name?  Would an NxN matrix be what you have in mind?  Also, I see both MySQL and SQL Server as tags.  Which database are you actually using here?

Comment: Are you working on SQL Server or MySQL? Also, what makes a column similar to another? Name? Do you have a naming convention in place? What about the data types?

Comment: I am currently using SQL Server 2012. And using TSQL

Comment: I doubt, that this wilt return what you are hoping for. What would you expect, when a customer's table has got an `ID` column, while a Sales table has got `CustomerID`. Same content with differing name... Furthermore I doubt, that the idea *same name == same content" works in all cases... 200 tables, each of which has got several columns... This is quite a lot of names...

Comment: @tim Columns have the same name in duplicate tables but it's just that some of the columns may be missing from the duplicate table.

Comment: @Shnugo - Maybe a percentage column which would show only if the matching columns are greater than lets say 75% for the duplicate table.

Comment: This sounds like there are many structurally similar tables, covering the same content? I hope you need this to solve this severe design flaw :-D

Comment: @Shnugo Thats the plan. That's why I am looking a way to find similar tables. Currently its a manual process which is definitely not fun.

Comment: This is a good plan one ought to support :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH PrepareData AS
(
    SELECT c1.TABLE_CATALOG AS c1_Cat,c1.TABLE_SCHEMA AS c1_Sch,c1.TABLE_NAME AS c1_Nam
          ,c2.TABLE_CATALOG AS c2_Cat,c2.TABLE_SCHEMA AS c2_Sch,c2.TABLE_NAME AS c2_Nam 
          ,COUNT(*) AS IdenticalColumns
          ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS x WHERE x.TABLE_CATALOG=c1.TABLE_CATALOG
                                                                AND x.TABLE_SCHEMA=c1.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                                                AND x.TABLE_NAME=c1.TABLE_NAME) AS CountT1
          ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS x WHERE x.TABLE_CATALOG=c2.TABLE_CATALOG
                                                                AND x.TABLE_SCHEMA=c2.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                                                AND x.TABLE_NAME=c2.TABLE_NAME) AS CountT2
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1
    FULL OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2 ON c1.TABLE_NAME<>c2.TABLE_NAME
                                                 AND c1.COLUMN_NAME=c2.COLUMN_NAME
    WHERE c1.TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL AND c2.TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY c1.TABLE_CATALOG,c1.TABLE_SCHEMA,c1.TABLE_NAME
            ,c2.TABLE_CATALOG,c2.TABLE_SCHEMA,c2.TABLE_NAME 
)
,ComputeSimilarity AS
(
    SELECT *
         ,CAST(IdenticalColumns AS FLOAT) / CAST(CountT1 AS FLOAT) AS  Factor1
         ,CAST(IdenticalColumns AS FLOAT) / CAST(CountT1 AS FLOAT) AS  Factor2
    FROM PrepareData
)
SELECT *
FROM ComputeSimilarity
WHERE Factor1>0.75 OR Factor2>0.75;
```

The idea: Join all columns on *the same column name but different table name*. Count the fitting columns and relate them to the overall count of columns.

Hint: This is returning VIEWs too. You can join `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to find the type.

Hint2: You get each result twice, one with *A to B* and again with *B to A*.

Comment: Wow man. This is what I was looking for. Thanks. I will test it out and let you know the results